# MacBook Pro sleeps unexpectedly and runs fans at high speed, even after SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power-management

My MacBook Pro (15 in Retina, early 2013, macOS 10.14.5) sleeps unexpectedly, although there is enough charge in the battery. To wake it up, I must connect the power supply. Furthermore, the fans run at high speed every now and then, even though the MacBook isn't under heavy usage and is properly ventilated.

I reset the SMC according to these instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295, but the problems went on. I checked the computer with EtreCheck (core version) and coconutBattery; both detected no issues.

What else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

Run diagnostics on the Mac as follows:

1. Disconnect all external devices
2. Go to **Apple Menu —> Restart**
3. Immediately press and hold down the <kbd>D</kbd> key while your Mac restarts
4. Keep holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key until you see the screen listing different languages appears
5. Click English.  Apple Diagnostics starts automatically.

Common results could be:

- Wi-Fi — a failure of the AirPort wireless card (4AIR)
- Hard disk and SSD (4HDD)
- Logic board (4IRP)
- Memory — RAM (4MEM)
- External disk (4MHD)
- Fans (4MOT)
- Processor (4PRC)
- Video/graphics card (4YDC)

I'd recommend you see if you have a fan issue: 4MOT

Comment: Thank you! Apple Diagnostics doesn't run. (It says "Unable to run diagnostics. DEC500"; then it boots into Internet Recovery, which fails saying "apple.com/support -1007D".) Is there another way to test the fans? Could a fan issue also be an explanation for the sudden sleep?

Comment: I tried to run Apple Diagnostics another time, but it didn't work. (The MacBook booted into Internet Recovery again and this time failed saying "Error: 0x80000000000003, Cannot Load 'EFI/Drivers/TestSupport.efi', Status: 0x00000003".) Maybe the MacBook has a EFI problem, but in my opinion this wouldn't explain the problems it has while running macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Open it up and blow out the dust.
Do a PRAM reset along with the SMC reset.
Let us know if it is still happening and we can go from there.

Comment: Thank you! I did the PRAM reset, and now I'm observing the MacBook's behaviour for a few days. I'll open and clean the MacBook, but I have to buy this screwdriver first ...

Comment: I opened the MacBook and blew out the dust. And I did a PRAM reset (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and another SMC reset. The MacBook still has the two problems.

Answer (score 0):

A local Mac repair shop advised me to do a clean reinstall of macOS and to make sure that the EFI partition is reinstalled as well. I did this, but the problems are still there.

With the release of macOS 11 Big Sur, I learned that this Mac will no longer get updates after autumn 2022. I will therefore not continue to search for solutions to the problems.